# WAMP phpMyAdmin always redirects to old version

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I have followed [these](https://john-dugan.com/upgrade-phpmyadmin-wamp/) steps to update phpMyAdmin.

TL;DR I have downloaded version 5.0.2 and placed the folder in `C:/Wamp/apps`, along with the old 4.8.4 version. I have also copied `config.inc.php` from the old version and modified `C:/Wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf` to look like so:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/Wamp/apps/phpmyadmin5.0.2/"

<Directory "C:/Wamp/apps/phpmyadmin5.0.2/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    
    <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
    </ifDefine>
    
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </ifDefine>
</Directory>
```

The file is exactly the same as before, with only the version numbers changed.

---

But when I go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, I see that phpMyAdmin is still on the old version:

[image: Version information: 4.8.4]

---

Thanks to a deprecation message on top of the page (that I assume is because I upgraded PHP), I can see that the path to the phpMyAdmin folder is still the old one:

```
Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in C:\Wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.8.4\libraries\classes\Url.php on line 251
```

---

If I rename (or delete) `C:/Wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.8.4/`, I get a "**403 Forbidden**" page when trying to access `localhost/phpmyadmin`. If I rename `C:/Wamp/apps/phpmyadmin5.0.2/` to `C:/Wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.8.4/`, version 5.0.2 is used. Of course, this would "solve" the problem, but I'd like to know what causes it.

After renaming again the new phpMyAdmin folder with its correct version, I can add a new file in `C:/Wamp/alias/` that looks exactly like the one above but with `Alias /myadmin` instead of `Alias /phpmyadmin`. Then, when I go to `localhost/myadmin`, the correct version is used. Of course, that's another "solution", but again, I would like to know why Wamp keeps looking for version 4.8.4 and how it's possible to change that and access version 5 from `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

---

If it helps, I am using WampServer 3.1.7.

Thanks.

Comment: WHY dont you use the ADDON feature to install `phpMyAdmin 5.0.2`. You could also upgrade to the latest WAMPServer currently V3.2.3. Look in the Backup Repo as finding ADDONS is so much easier there than SourceForge [which is here](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, I'll check it out! But I don't want to update Wamp due compatibility issues.